# Libgdx Android Gradle Build Errors

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

My desktop application works, but my android application does not. there are a few errors in the launcher file, and I assume they have something to do with the package and or connected libraries. I have tried many things, but cannot get to the bottom of it. Here is the AndroidLauncher code with errors on commented lines. Thanks much.

```
package com.ahewdev.spacepace.android;
import android.os.Bundle; //----------ERROR
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication; //-------ERROR
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration; //-ERROR
import com.ahewdev.spacepace.spacepace; //---------ERROR
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override //---------ERROR
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //---------ERROR
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new spacepace(), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: what particular error messages do you get?

Comment: @ReneGroeschke That's the odd thing; none. It builds succesfuly, and there are no lint errors, but when I launch the app on android it crashes immediately. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't asked for the right permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.

If you use things like networking or the user's location you have to declare you want to use them in AndroidManifest.xml, or the application will crash at startup.

Here's the default list of permission groups you can use:
[Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html)

And here's the LibGDX article on permissions:
[LibGDX wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-&-configuration#permissions)

I hope this solves your problem!